# Background Color of rows Table UI

Tags: tables

This is a question about the UI of a table. Does implementing 1 and 2 at the same time lead to better UI/UX? Or is it too much?

1. Change the background color of the table rows alternately.
2. Change the background color of the target line when hovering over a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do either based on the action

if the rows are readonly then just do alternate background color
if rows are clickable then just highlighting should be fine but make sure borders are proper to seperate rows from one another

Answer (score 1):

If your 2) is not conflicting with 1) i.e. the colour which you are choosing to show over hovering is not getting mixed or hidden with background, it's fine. You can try it and change accordingly.

Comment: Hey @jun, Stack overflow is the right place for this type of question.